# Change legend trace color independently of actual trace data in plotly r

Tags: r, r-plotly

How do I change the color of the marker in a plotly legend, independently of what is shown?

```
library(plotly)
library(data.table)
data=data.table(x=seq(1,100), y=rnorm(100), group = sample(letters[1:3], ,size=100, replace=T))
plot_ly(type="scatter", mode="markers") %>% 
  add_trace(data=data[group=="a"], x=~x,y=~y, name="Metric", legendgroup="m", showlegend=T, marker=list(size=10,color="red")) %>% 
  add_trace(data=data[group=="b"], x=~x,y=~y, name="Metric2", legendgroup="m", showlegend=F, marker=list(size=10,color="blue")) %>% 
  add_trace(data=data[group=="c"], x=~x,y=~y, name="Metric3", legendgroup="m", showlegend=F, marker=list(size=10,color="green")) %>% 
  layout(showlegend=T)
```

I want the single red circle in the legend to be black, instead of red, while I want the points on the plot to be red/blue/green as they currently are.

[image: Example Plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of getting this effect is by including `add_markers()` with `visible = 'legendonly'` and setting `showlegend = F` for all your `add_trace()` lines:

```
library(plotly)
library(data.table)
data=data.table(x=seq(1,100), y=rnorm(100), group = sample(letters[1:3], ,size=100, replace=T))
plot_ly(type="scatter", mode="markers") %>% 
  add_markers(x = data$x[1], y = data$y[1], name = 'Metric', visible = 'legendonly', legendgroup='m', showlegend = T, marker = list(size = 10, color = 'black')) %>% 
  add_trace(data=data[group=="a"], x=~x,y=~y, name="Metric", legendgroup="m", showlegend=F, marker=list(size=10,color="red")) %>% 
  add_trace(data=data[group=="b"], x=~x,y=~y, name="Metric2", legendgroup="m", showlegend=F, marker=list(size=10,color="blue")) %>% 
  add_trace(data=data[group=="c"], x=~x,y=~y, name="Metric3", legendgroup="m", showlegend=F, marker=list(size=10,color="green")) %>%
  layout(showlegend=T)
```

which gives
[image: scatterplot with blue, red and green dots]

Comment: thanks @tivd, that is helpful. This unfortunately adds the point to the plot when clicking on the legend, but I  note that adding this first (before the traces), and setting x and y to an actual data point, will minimize this effect, because the additional fake point will be hidden behind an actual point.  Also, need to add `legendgroup="m"` to ensure that this legend is linked to the data traces

Comment: @langtang - I added your suggestions. This is a bit of a quick-and-dirty solution of course. Maybe somebody else is able to provide a 'proper' way of doing this (unfortunately I'm not).